# Add / Clear MergedDictionaries from code behind in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, app.xaml, mergeddictionaries

I am trying to change the MergedDictionaries from code behind in windows 8 application. My App.xaml looks like below,

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/TestTheme.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In that i am trying to remove all ResourceDictionary, and add a new ResourceDictionary from code behind. I searched in web but wont got any solution. Need a help to get this thing done.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no a easy solution for your question. Maybe you can load a resource dictionary and read all the items, and add the objects to the other dictionary as it's explained in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh968442.aspx)

> You are permitted to add items to an existing ResourceDictionary by
>   calling Add (C# or Visual Basic) or Insert (C++/CX). You could add to
>   either immediate resources or app resources. Either of these API calls
>   requires a key, which satisfies the requirement that each item in a
>   ResourceDictionary have a key. However, items that you add to a
>   ResourceDictionary at run time are not relevant to XAML resource
>   references at all. The necessary lookup for XAML resource references
>   happens when XAML is being parsed as the app is loaded (or a theme
>   change is detected), and collections that are modified at run time are
>   either not available or are reset.